# How can I add configuration for an existing project in Clion?

Tags: configuration, ide, clion

I just installed the Clion on Linux and now face some problems. If I create a new project in Clion, I can choose a c/c++ configuration from some given options like in the linked photo.
[finding configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wSF7r.png)

So the work of configuration will be done. I can run or debug my program without problems.

However, if I open an existing file using Clion, I need to add configuration but no finding any given options. I tried to "edit configuration" but can't find any configuration like those in the linked pickture above.
Just like this below:
[no finding configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tnl70.png)

My question is: how could I add configuration for a existing project in Clion like for a new project? Or how could I find thoes configuration in the first linked picture?

Thanks for help.